# How to use a local typescript declaration file for an installed module?

Tags: typescript

When I installed a non popular module that doesn't have a published type declaration under `@types` namespace, I'm stuck. I know how to write a declaration file, but I don't know how to make typescript compiler aware of it. The typescript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) doesn't mention how to do it. The docs only mention to search for type declaration and if not found, publish a new one but doesn't mention how to do it without publishing.

So, say I installed a package named `xyz` and I know the public api that it exposes. Then, I write a type declaration file that matches the exposed api. Then, How to make typescript compiler aware of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `<module-name>.d.ts` file to your project, and TypeScript should become aware of it automatically. You don't need to import it or anything, just to be in the folders processed by TypeScript

Comment: Could you be more specific, where should I put that file? Say, all my typescript codes is under `src/` directory, where should I put that file?

Comment: Notice: In the definition file, the author must wrap the exported members in: `declare module "xyz" { ... }`.

Comment: @MasBagol, put it under `src/`, yes. You can also add a folder `types` under you `src` if you want, it doesn't matter. And no, you don't need to 'export' anything, as it is an ambient declaration file.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks :)

Comment: Very important that the file begin with

```
declare module '<module name>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your project include a `tsconfig.json` file? If so you can specifiy paths to type definitions under the compilerOptions:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
   }
}
```

[About 'tsconfig.json' in the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)